# How to join results of two models in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to make a user panel in which each user's profile info (like avatar, joined date, etc.) are being displayed along with their posts. Here is the view that render the threads:

```
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Listing of posts in a thread."""
    posts = Post.objects.select_related('creator') \
        .filter(topic=topic_id).order_by("created")
    posts = mk_paginator(request, posts, DJANGO_SIMPLE_FORUM_REPLIES_PER_PAGE)
    topic = Topic.objects.get(pk=topic_id)
    topic.visits += 1
    topic.save()

    return render_to_response("myforum/topic.html", add_csrf(request, posts=posts, pk=topic_id,
        topic=topic), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The Topic model is:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True)
    forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    visits = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

And the UserProfile model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices= COUTNRY_CHOICES, blank=True)
    avatar = ImageWithThumbsField(), upload_to='images', sizes=((32,32),(150,150),(200,200)), blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
```

The problem is how best to join these two tables so that userprofile fields can be displayed in topic.html along with username?

Answer (score 2):

Add them to context since you already have a database relation Users and Topics.

```
# add this to context
topic = Topic.objects.get(pk=topic_id)
creator = topic.creator.get().profile # This pulls the user object from creator field
context['creator'] = creator # Add to context
```

Now you can use the 'creator' context to pull fields

```
<h1>{{ creator.name }}</h1>
```

as for the avatar, if you have your media root set in settings you simply use an

```
<img src="/media/images/{{ creator.avatar }}">
```

Oh and also you can save alot of time by using ListView and DetailView part of Django's class based views.

Sorry forgot to mention you should add a related name to your one to one,

```
username = OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
```

Comment: Interesting, however after adding these lines and migrating the database I   get `'User' object has no attribute 'get'` referring to the line  `creator = topic.creator.get().profile `. Any ideas?